# Very simple module failing. Error: 91, Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

This code simply pulls information from a table, and inserts it into a temporary table.  From there, it updates the rows with the correct program name that correlates to the program id given, which is where it fails.

I'm not sure why this simple module won't run, I've declared the variable, as well as initialized it.  The query is super simple, as well.  Any help would  be appreciated -- I have got to me missing something painfully obvious.

```
Dim year As String
Dim month As String
Dim contract As String
Dim programId As String
Dim ConsumerId As String
Dim programName As String

Dim db As Database

Dim Records As DAO.recordset
Dim Records2 As DAO.recordset


year = Forms!formAllentownMasterGeneration!cboYear
month = Forms!formAllentownMasterGeneration!cboMonth
contract = Forms!formAllentownMasterGeneration!cboContract

'Empty temporary table
strSQL = "DELETE * FROM billing_days_allentown1_temp"

 DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

 'Gather and insert consumer information into temp table
 strSQL = "INSERT INTO Billing_days_allentown1_temp (consumer_id, program_id, lname, fname, dob, transport_type, memo) SELECT consumer_info.consumer_id, consumer_info.program_id, consumer_info.lname, consumer_info.fname, consumer_info.dob, consumer_info.transport_type, consumer_info.memo FROM consumer_info WHERE contract_name = [contract]"

DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

'Get ID's of all consumers in temp table so we can find program names
strSQL = "SELECT consumer_id, program_id FROM Billing_days_allentown1_temp"

Set Records = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT consumer_id, program_id FROM billing_days_allentown1_temp")

While Not Records.EOF

ConsumerId = Records!Fields(0)
programId = Records!Fields(1)

strSQL2 = "SELECT name FROM program_info where program_id = [programId]"
Set Records2 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT name FROM program_info where program_id = [programId]")

programName = Records2!Fields(0)

strSQL2 = "UPDATE billing_days_allentown1_temp SET program_name = [ProgramName] WHERE program_id = programId and consumer_id = [consumerId]"
DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL2)

Records.MoveNext

Wend

DoCmd.Close acForm, "formAllentownMasterGeneration"
```

Additionally (but admittedly a problem I haven't looked into yet), it prompts me for the contract name, despite providing it in the form.  I'm sure I am referencing the variable wrong in a query; but my VBA is pretty rusty.  If it's a quick fix, I'd appreciate someone pointing that out as well, otherwise it's something I'll fix on my own in due time.

Thank you.

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: Include `Set db = CurrentDb` somewhere before the first call to `db.OpenRecordset`

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit my post.  It fails on: Set Records = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT consumer_id, program_id FROM billing_days_allentown1_temp")

Comment: Thank you for the quick response HansUp, worked perfectly.  I knew I had to be missing something.

Comment: About that other issue ... do you mean here? `WHERE contract_name = [contract]`  What is `[contract]` supposed to represent?  You have a VBA variable named *contract*, but the db engine doesn't know anything about VBA variables.  If that is the issue, you can include the variable's value instead of its name in your SQL statement.  Or reference `Forms!formAllentownMasterGeneration!cboContract` directly in the SQL statement.  Or use a parameter query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...it should clean up your SQL statements a little...and pass the variables, not [variable]

```
Dim year As String
Dim month As String
Dim contract As String
Dim programId As String
Dim ConsumerId As String
Dim programName As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strSQL2 As String
Dim db As Database

Dim Records As DAO.recordset
Dim Records2 As DAO.recordset

year = Me.cboYear   '<--- Assuming you are on Forms!formAllentownMasterGeneration - you can use Me.
month = Me.cboMonth
contract = Me.cboContract

'Empty temporary table
strSQL = "DELETE * FROM billing_days_allentown1_temp"

 DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

 'Gather and insert consumer information into temp table
 strSQL = "INSERT INTO Billing_days_allentown1_temp (consumer_id, program_id, lname, fname, dob, transport_type, memo) " & _
          "SELECT consumer_info.consumer_id, consumer_info.program_id, consumer_info.lname, consumer_info.fname, consumer_info.dob, consumer_info.transport_type, consumer_info.memo " & _
          "FROM consumer_info " & _
          "WHERE contract_name =" & contract

DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

'Get ID's of all consumers in temp table so we can find program names
strSQL = "SELECT consumer_id, program_id " & _
         "FROM Billing_days_allentown1_temp"

Set Records = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

While Not Records.EOF
  ConsumerId = Records!Fields(0)
  programId = Records!Fields(1)

  strSQL2 = "SELECT name " & _
            "FROM program_info " & _
            "WHERE program_id = " & programId
  Set Records2 = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL2)

  ProgramName = Records2!Fields(0)

  strSQL2 = "UPDATE billing_days_allentown1_temp " & _
            "SET program_name = " & ProgramName & " " & _
            "WHERE program_id = " & programId & " and consumer_id = " & consumerId
  DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL2)

  Records.MoveNext

Wend

DoCmd.Close acForm, "formAllentownMasterGeneration"
```